# Xamarin.Forms.Droid Resource, Ambiguous Terms/ Build Action's Randomly Changing Missing Resources

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm having issue's with missing resources on builds.

I found why The Rescource.Designer.cs is set to Build to => Compile.

Now If I set it to Android Resource 1 of 2 things happen

Scenario 1:

I get a Ambiguous Error on Debug for

```
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
```

> Resource' is an ambiguous reference between
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource' and
>   'Plugin.FirebasePushNotification.Resource'

If I Delete bin/obj And Rebuild Then The Build action for Designer is back to => Compile

Scnario 2 I get the Following Error

> Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Aapt.targets(3,3):
>   Error APT1045: invalid resource directory name:
>   MyPath/obj/Release/res/ resource.designer.cs " resource.designer.cs".
>   (APT1045)

If anyone can help me with this, There next to no information I can find in regards to these

If I resolve the Ambiguous issue It cant find the Toolbar or Tabbar

Answer (score 0):

To solve the Ambiguous error you might want to try use a full name of the class, like:

```
TabLayoutResource = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
```

or aliases:

```
using AndroidRs = Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.Resource;
...
TabLayoutResource = AndroidRs.Layout.Tabbar;
```

Also you can refer to [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/using-namespaces) for more options